# Merge <tr> <td> in php foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I have a dynamic table where a `foreach` loop generate every tr and the first td values
My problem is that every tr has 2nd 3rd 4th and 5th td column. These are also generated by a new `foreach`.
What is the smartest way to synchronise these loops to show data correctly?

Comment: The smartest way would be to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is very simple:

```
<?php 
$rows = '5'; // Number of rows that you want
echo "<table>";
for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){          
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$tr}*1</td>"; 
    for($td=2;$td<=5;$td++){ 
        echo "<td>{$tr}*{$td}</td>"; 
    } 
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```